# Запретить одинаковые символы edit1, edit2 / Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Как запретить водить одинаковые символы edit1 + edit2. К примеру если символ **+** введен в **edit1** то ввести его в **edit2** нельзя.
Сделала вот так, работает:

```
if (Edit1.Text = '+') and (Edit2.Text = '+') then
Edit3.Clear;
```

Но я так понимаю это нужно прописывать для каждого символа. Может есть вариант по проще, в смысле что бы не писать для каждого символа код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...
Edit1.OnKeyPress := EditKeyPress;
Edit2.OnKeyPress := EditKeyPress;
...

procedure TSomeForm.EditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if ((Sender = Edit1) and (Pos(Key, Edit2.Text) > 0)) or
     ((Sender = Edit2) and (Pos(Key, Edit1.Text) > 0)) then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решила вот таким образом:

```
if (Edit1.Text = Edit2.Text) then
Edit2.Clear;
```